# [Error [ValidationError]: "x" is required]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a full stack app in a team setting using React on the frontend and firebase on the backend.

I filled out all the forms on the frontend and as soon as I clicked 'Publish' to send this data to Firestore, I get an error saying the logo is required, which is very weird. I remember putting it like a minute ago

Error from Firebase:

```
{
    "data": "ValidationError: \"logo\" is required",
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "content-length": "35",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {
            "FormData": null
        },
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "http://localhost:9000/add",
        "data": "{\"body\":\"{\\\"teamType\\\":1,\\\"logo\\\":{},\\\"title\\\":\\\"Never gonna give you up\\\",\\\"roles\\\":[{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Full Stack Developer\\\",\\\"compSkills\\\":[\\\"Swift\\\"],\\\"reqSkills\\\":[\\\"ios\\\"],\\\"hours\\\":\\\"7\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"We're no strangers to love\\\\n\\\",\\\"location\\\":[\\\"Greece\\\"]}],\\\"members\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Rick Astley\\\",\\\"linkedinUrl\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"photo\\\":{},\\\"email\\\":\\\"gideon@quantico.com\\\"}],\\\"startDate\\\":\\\"2022-10-27\\\",\\\"endDate\\\":\\\"2022-11-05\\\"}\"}"
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

`LogoTitle.js`:

```
import { useState, useRef, memo } from "react";
import "./LogoTitle.css";
import image from "../../Assets/LogoTitle/image.svg";
import infoCircle from "../../Assets/LogoTitle/info-circle.svg";
function LogoTitle(props) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0.3);
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [typing, setTyping] = useState(false);
  const inputFile = useRef(null);
  function handleClick() {
    setActive(true);
  }
  function handleBlur() {
    setActive(false);
  }
  function typingDone(e) {
    if (title !== "") {
      setOpacity(1);
      if (selectedImage) props.invokeLogoTitle(null, true);
      else props.invokeLogoTitle(null, false);
    } else {
      setOpacity(0.3);
      props.invokeLogoTitle(null, false);
    }
  }
  function handleTitleChange(e) {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
    props.setTitle(e.target.value);
  }
  function handleChange(e) {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setSelectedImage(e.target.files[0]);
      props.setLogo(e.target.files[0]);
      console.log(" ~ file: LogoTitle.js ~ line 36 ~ handleChange ~ e.target.files[0]", e.target.files[0])
    }

    if (title !== "" && (e.target.files[0] || selectedImage)) {
      props.invokeLogoTitle(null, true);
    } else {
      props.invokeLogoTitle(null, false);
    }
  }
  function handleImage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputFile.current.click();
  }
  return (
    <div
      className="companyLogoTitle"
      onClick={() => {
        handleClick();
        props.invokeActivity(null, 1);
      }}
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        handleClick();
        props.invokeActivity(null, 1);
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        if (!typing) {
          handleBlur();
          props.invokeActivity(null, 0);
        } else props.invokeActivity(null, 0, true);
      }}
      tabIndex="-1"
      style={
        active
          ? {
              border: "1px solid #793EF5",
              boxShadow: "0px 24px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
            }
          : null
      }
    >
      <input
        type="file"
        id="file"
        ref={inputFile}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        accept="image/*"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <div className="logoHeader">
        <p className="logoHeaderText">Company Logo & Apprenticeship Title</p>
        <img src={infoCircle} alt=""></img>
      </div>
      <div className="logoTitle">
        <div className="logoRectangle" onClick={handleImage}>
          {selectedImage ? (
            <img
              className="logoRectangle"
              alt=""
              src={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)}
            ></img>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <img
            className="uploadImage"
            src={image}
            alt=""
            style={
              selectedImage
                ? {
                    marginTop: "0px",
                    bottom: "23.5px",
                  }
                : null
            }
          ></img>
        </div>
        <input
          type={"text"}
          className="logoTitleText"
          placeholder="Enter Apprenticeship Title"
          onBlur={() => {
            handleBlur();
            props.invokeActivity(null, 0, false);
            typingDone();
            setTyping(false);
          }}
          onChange={handleTitleChange}
          onClick={() => {
            setOpacity(1);
            props.invokeActivity(null, 1, true);
            setTyping(true);
          }}
          style={{ opacity: opacity }}
        ></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default memo(LogoTitle);
```

Apprenticeship object schema in JSX as well as Firestore

```
const apprenticeship={
    teamType:type,
    logo:logo,
    title:title,
    compDesc:undefined,
    appDesc:undefined,
    introVideo:undefined,
    roles:roles,
    members: admin,
    startDate:startDate,
    endDate:endDate,
  };
```

To confirm that logo is not null:

```
File {name: 'IMG_20220713_171851_342.jpg', lastModified: 1662294961950, lastModifiedDate: Sun Sep 04 2022 14:36:01 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 150222, …}
lastModified: 1662294961950
lastModifiedDate: Sun Sep 04 2022 14:36:01 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time) {}
name: "IMG_20220713_171851_342.jpg"
size: 150222
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
```

Comment: As mentioned  in this [documentation](https://support.google.com/transitpartners/answer/10728367?hl=en&ref_topic=6377382#zippy=%2Cmissing-required-file), the error “[Error [ValidationError]: "x" is required]” occurs when the files are grouped under a directory within the zip file. The zip file must contain individual files all on one level with no sub-directory structure.

Make sure logo file is not under zipped file or not under sub-directory.

Comment: Nope this is a jpg file.